# Effect like screensaver in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

my question is: How can I launch an action after a time of inactivity user in Javascript?, for example, in my app the user can navigate across the content and leave it in a section, lapsed a specific time, return to the homepage. Any idea?

Comment: What have you already done?

Comment: My web have different sections and one home page. I need return to homepage when there is no action for a lapse time. The action could be refresh the page.

Comment: You can eventually use `requestIdleCallback`, but support is extremely limited right now. 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the javascript setTimeout function

```
var myVar;
$(document).ready(function () {
    myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 300000);
    $(document).click(function () {
       clearTimeout(myVar);
       myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 300000);
    }); 
});
function myFunction () {
    alert("TIME OUT!");
}
```